# Append several columns to another SharePoint list using event receiver

Tags: custom-list, event-receivers, event-handlers

I am working on two SharePoint list:List 1 is overview of servers including: Server Name, Purpose, status etc.. List 2 is change log on each server, it got an lookup column that connects to Server Name in List 1. What I want to do is each time a new log is added/deleted/updated in List 2, it will automatically add/delete/update in List1, because there will be several logs for one server and we are not using Infopath for repeating section, I decide to use C# code and build a Event Receiver. But I only start with c# and have no idea how to write them at all. Now I only got this. Could anyone show me how the code would be like, I will be so grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace AppendListColumn.AppendColumn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class AppendColumn : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item is being added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// An item is being updated.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdating(properties);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// An item is being deleted.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemDeleting(properties);
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Celia

Answer (score 1):

```
  public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);
        sendItemTolist2(properties);
    }

 private void sendItemTolist2(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        SPWeb webPropertiesListItem = properties.Web;
                        using (SPSite oSite = webPropertiesListItem.Site)
                        {
                        //if you want list2 is on another sitecollection
                            using (SPWeb webRH = oSite.OpenWeb("Name Web"))
                            {
                                webRH.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                SPList EventList = webRH.Lists["List2"];
                                SPListItem EventListElmt = EventList.Items.Add();
                                EventListElmt["Title"] = _currentItem["Title"];
                                ...
                                EventListElmt.Update();
                            }

                            //if list2 is on the same site then just copy to list2


                                webPropertiesListItem.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                SPList EventList = webPropertiesListItem.Lists["List2"];
                                SPListItem EventListElmt = EventList.Items.Add();
                                EventListElmt["Title"] = _currentItem["Title"];
                                ...
                                EventListElmt.Update();
                        }
                    });
                    }
```